# Show Upload Progress for Image Upload to Amazon S3 using Swift 3 and Amazon SDK

Tags: swift, file-upload, amazon-s3, swift3, ios10

I am able to successfully upload an image to Amazon S3, but I can't seem to figure out how to show the progress of it doing so.

I'm currently uploading like so.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreData
import AWSCore
import AWSCognito
import AWSS3
import MobileCoreServices
import AWSMobileAnalytics
```

in my upload button I have the following code...

```
let myIdentityPoolId = "us-west-2:dca2beb4-9a67-etc....etc..."
                let credentialsProvider:AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.usWest2, identityPoolId: myIdentityPoolId)
                let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.usWest2, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
                AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

self.uploadImage(filename)
```

This is the uploadImage function...

```
func uploadImage(filename:String){
        print("AWS Upload Image Attempt...")
        //defining bucket and upload file name
        let S3BucketName: String = "distribution-tech-mobile-live"
        let filepath = "\(AppDelegate.appDelegate.applicationDocumentsDirectory())/\(filename)"
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
        let S3UploadKeyName = filename //TODO: Change this later

        let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
        uploadRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
        uploadRequest?.key = filename
        uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        uploadRequest?.body = imageURL
        uploadRequest?.serverSideEncryption = AWSS3ServerSideEncryption.awsKms
        uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.amountUploaded = totalBytesSent // To show the updating data status in label.
                self.fileSize = totalBytesExpectedToSend
                print("\(totalBytesSent)/\(totalBytesExpectedToSend)")
            })
        }

        self.uploadCompletionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if ((error) != nil){
                    print("Failed with error")
                    print("Error: \(error!)");
                }
                else{
                    print("Sucess")
                }
            })
        }

        let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

        transferUtility.uploadFile(imageURL, bucket: S3BucketName, key: S3UploadKeyName, contentType: "image/jpeg", expression: expression, completionHander: uploadCompletionHandler).continue({ (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if let exception = task.exception {
                print("Exception: \(exception.description)")
            }
            if let _ = task.result {
                print("Upload Starting!")
            }

            return nil;
        })

    }
```

I got the code for image uploading progress from another thread but there solution doesn't seem to work or I'm misunderstanding it.

[Upload image AWS S3 bucket in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348696/upload-image-aws-s3-bucket-in-swift?rq=1), and this thread ([Swift - AWS S3 Upload Image from Photo Library and download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240317/swift-aws-s3-upload-image-from-photo-library-and-download-it)).  They both have 2 different ways to do it, the last link I couldn't get its way to work either.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where's the problem? You have `.uploadProgress` closure which provide you with uploading progress, and you even use it in your code. Add there some code updating progress in UI and it's done.

Comment: The problem I was mixing and matching two different methods of uploading, so I was doing upload progress for a different way of doing it before and triggering an upload using an alternative way so the upload progress never worked.  I got confused because of all the variants in answers regarding this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I found the solution to my problem, apparently I just didn't follow through enough.

Here is my new revised uploadImage function

```
func uploadImage(filename:String){
        print("AWS Upload Image Attempt...")
        //defining bucket and upload file name
        let S3BucketName: String = "distribution-tech-mobile-live"
        let filepath = "\(AppDelegate.appDelegate.applicationDocumentsDirectory())/\(filename)"
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
        let S3UploadKeyName = filename //TODO: Change this later

        let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
        uploadRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
        uploadRequest?.key = S3UploadKeyName
        uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        uploadRequest?.body = imageURL
        uploadRequest?.serverSideEncryption = AWSS3ServerSideEncryption.awsKms
        uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.amountUploaded = totalBytesSent // To show the updating data status in label.
                self.fileSize = totalBytesExpectedToSend
                print("\(totalBytesSent)/\(totalBytesExpectedToSend)")
            })
        }

        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
        transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continue(with: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), withSuccessBlock: { (taskk: AWSTask) -> Any? in
            if taskk.error != nil {
                // Error.
                print("error")
            } else {
                // Do something with your result.
                print("something with result when its done")
            }
            return nil
        })

    }
```

This has spot for when result is done and during the upload progress and makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Can you show how to select image from imagepicker and generate URL and send to AWS by the same method as above. I'm stuck on this since hours now

Comment: Sure this is easy once I get in the office we can start a chat on here

Comment: I am using this method to show AWS upload progress. But media is not uploading on the S3. The method shows the upload progress and complete with success. When I am checking the image on S3 then we are not able to locate it.

Comment: AWSS3TransferManager is deprecated